# More details on NullPointerExceptions?

Tags: java

The most annoying part about NullPointerExceptions is how hilariously nonverbose they are. At best it tells you which line was affected, but never which variable. If every programmer would write with as little coupling and command chaining as possible, that would of course not be a problem, but there are cases where this is not possible:

```
    someCollection.removeAll(someOtherCollection);
```

In this example, we could get a NullPointerException if either variable is empty. The only way to find out which one caused the Exception is to manually debug that specific part of code.

Is there some library out there improving the verbosity of NullPointerExceptions, even at the cost of some performance? Something like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException (variable: someCollection)
     at ClassName.method(org.package.ClassName:60)
```

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: "The only way to find out which one caused the Exception is to manually debug that specific part of code." That's not correct. The stack trace will tell you whether it happened inside `removeAll` or not.

Comment: Yes this is **finally** fixed in Java 14. JEP: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Okay, bad example then. But there definitely are cases where it's not working.

Comment: @Joni Oh hell yeah! Didn't even notice it was already out (been on Java 11 so far). Thanks for the heads up!